# Single Post like button animation is working but multiple post mean first post button only working

Tags: javascript, php, css, html, animation

I have code in like button code with css here single news-feed mean button is working but multiple news-feed mean first post button only working if i click other post button also first post button only working. I using post UI and according to the total post count looping the UI, for this animation fully working html with css not using Javascript, Please give me a feedback or advice me how i can fix this issues.

**CSS Code :**

```
svg {
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow: visible;
    width: 60px;
    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: -45px;
}

svg #heart {
    transform-origin: center;
    animation: animateHeartOut .3s linear forwards;
}

svg #main-circ {
    transform-origin: 29.5px 29.5px;
}

#checkbox-ins {
    display: none;
}

#checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #heart {
    transform: scale(0.2);
    fill: #ddd810;
    animation: animateHeart .3s linear forwards .25s;
}

#checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #main-circ {
    transition: all 2s;
    animation: animateCircle .3s linear forwards;
    opacity: 1;
}

#checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp1 {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: .1s all .3s;
}

#checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp1 #oval1 {
    transform: scale(0) translate(0, -30px);
    transform-origin: 0 0 0;
    transition: .5s transform .3s;
}

#checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp1 #oval2 {
    transform: scale(0) translate(10px, -50px);
    transform-origin: 0 0 0;
    transition: 1.5s transform .3s;
}

#checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp2 {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: .1s all .3s;
}

#checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp2 #oval1 {
    transform: scale(0) translate(30px, -15px);
    transform-origin: 0 0 0;
    transition: .5s transform .3s;
}

#checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp2 #oval2 {
    transform: scale(0) translate(60px, -15px);
    transform-origin: 0 0 0;
    transition: 1.5s transform .3s;
}

#checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp3 {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: .1s all .3s;
}

#checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp3 #oval1 {
    transform: scale(0) translate(30px, 0px);
    transform-origin: 0 0 0;
    transition: .5s transform .3s;
}

#checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp3 #oval2 {
    transform: scale(0) translate(60px, 10px);
    transform-origin: 0 0 0;
    transition: 1.5s transform .3s;
}

#checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp4 {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: .1s all .3s;
}

#checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp4 #oval1 {
    transform: scale(0) translate(30px, 15px);
    transform-origin: 0 0 0;
    transition: .5s transform .3s;
}

#checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp4 #oval2 {
    transform: scale(0) translate(40px, 50px);
    transform-origin: 0 0 0;
    transition: 1.5s transform .3s;
}

#checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp5 {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: .1s all .3s;
}

#checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp5 #oval1 {
    transform: scale(0) translate(-10px, 20px);
    transform-origin: 0 0 0;
    transition: .5s transform .3s;
}

#checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp5 #oval2 {
    transform: scale(0) translate(-60px, 30px);
    transform-origin: 0 0 0;
    transition: 1.5s transform .3s;
}

#checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp6 {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: .1s all .3s;
}

#checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp6 #oval1 {
    transform: scale(0) translate(-30px, 0px);
    transform-origin: 0 0 0;
    transition: .5s transform .3s;
}

#checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp6 #oval2 {
    transform: scale(0) translate(-60px, -5px);
    transform-origin: 0 0 0;
    transition: 1.5s transform .3s;
}

#checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp7 {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: .1s all .3s;
}

#checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp7 #oval1 {
    transform: scale(0) translate(-30px, -15px);
    transform-origin: 0 0 0;
    transition: .5s transform .3s;
}

#checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp7 #oval2 {
    transform: scale(0) translate(-55px, -30px);
    transform-origin: 0 0 0;
    transition: 1.5s transform .3s;
}

#checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp2 {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: .1s opacity .3s;
}

#checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp3 {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: .1s opacity .3s;
}

#checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp4 {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: .1s opacity .3s;
}

#checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp5 {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: .1s opacity .3s;
}

#checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp6 {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: .1s opacity .3s;
}

#checkbox-ins:checked+label svg #grp7 {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: .1s opacity .3s;
}

@keyframes animateCircle {
    40% {
        transform: scale(10);
        opacity: 1;
        fill: #ddd810;
    }
    55% {
        transform: scale(11);
        opacity: 1;
        fill: #ddd810;
    }
    65% {
        transform: scale(12);
        opacity: 1;
        fill: #ddd810;
    }
    75% {
        transform: scale(13);
        opacity: 1;
        fill: transparent;
        stroke: #ddd810;
        stroke-width: .5;
    }
    85% {
        transform: scale(17);
        opacity: 1;
        fill: transparent;
        stroke: #ddd810;
        stroke-width: .2;
    }
    95% {
        transform: scale(18);
        opacity: 1;
        fill: transparent;
        stroke: #ddd810;
        stroke-width: .1;
    }
    100% {
        transform: scale(19);
        opacity: 1;
        fill: transparent;
        stroke: #ddd810;
        stroke-width: 0;
    }
}

@keyframes animateHeart {
    0% {
        transform: scale(0.2);
    }
    40% {
        transform: scale(1.2);
    }
    100% {
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}

@keyframes animateHeartOut {
    0% {
        transform: scale(1.4);
    }
    100% {
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}
```

**HTML Code :**

```
<?php
 while($row->mysqli_fetch_assoc($newsfeed))
{
?>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-ins"/>
                                                                        <label for="checkbox-ins">
                                                                          <svg id="heart-svg" viewBox="467 392 58 57" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                                                            <g id="Group" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" transform="translate(467 392)">
                                                                              <path d="M25.82,40.35a1.67,1.67,0,0,0,.31.94l.94,1.36a1.8,1.8,0,0,0,1.36.73h3.24A1.76,1.76,0,0,0,33,42.65L34,41.29a1.69,1.69,0,0,0,
                                                                                       .32-.94v-2H25.92A13.27,13.27,0,0,0,25.82,40.35Zm-5-14.53a9.11,9.11,0,0,0,2.3,6.06,14.75,14.75,0,0,1,2.72,
                                                                                       4.81h8.36a16,16,0,0,1,2.72-4.81,8.92,8.92,0,0,0,2.3-6.06,9.2,9.2,0,0,0-18.4,0ZM30,21.64a4.19,4.19,0,0,0-4.18,4.18.9.9,0,0,
                                                                                       1-.84.84.89.89,0,0,1-.83-.84A5.84,5.84,0,0,1,30,20a.89.89,0,0,1,.84.83A.9.9,0,0,1,30,21.64Z" id="heart" fill="#AAB8C2"/>
                                                                              <circle id="main-circ" fill="#ddd810" opacity="0" cx="29.5" cy="29.5" r="1.5"/>

                                                                              <g id="grp7" opacity="0" transform="translate(7 6)">
                                                                                <circle id="oval1" fill="#ddd810" cx="2" cy="6" r="2"/>
                                                                                <circle id="oval2" fill="#ddd810" cx="5" cy="2" r="2"/>
                                                                              </g>

                                                                              <g id="grp6" opacity="0" transform="translate(0 28)">
                                                                                <circle id="oval1" fill="#ddd810" cx="2" cy="7" r="2"/>
                                                                                <circle id="oval2" fill="#ddd810" cx="3" cy="2" r="2"/>
                                                                              </g>

                                                                              <g id="grp3" opacity="0" transform="translate(52 28)">
                                                                                <circle id="oval2" fill="#ddd810" cx="2" cy="7" r="2"/>
                                                                                <circle id="oval1" fill="#ddd810" cx="4" cy="2" r="2"/>
                                                                              </g>

                                                                              <g id="grp2" opacity="0" transform="translate(44 6)">
                                                                                <circle id="oval2" fill="#ddd810" cx="5" cy="6" r="2"/>
                                                                                <circle id="oval1" fill="#ddd810" cx="2" cy="2" r="2"/>
                                                                              </g>

                                                                              <g id="grp5" opacity="0" transform="translate(14 50)">
                                                                                <circle id="oval1" fill="#ddd810" cx="6" cy="5" r="2"/>
                                                                                <circle id="oval2" fill="#ddd810" cx="2" cy="2" r="2"/>
                                                                              </g>

                                                                              <g id="grp4" opacity="0" transform="translate(35 50)">
                                                                                <circle id="oval1" fill="#ddd810" cx="6" cy="5" r="2"/>
                                                                                <circle id="oval2" fill="#ddd810" cx="2" cy="2" r="2"/>
                                                                              </g>

                                                                              <g id="grp1" opacity="0" transform="translate(24)">
                                                                                <circle id="oval1" fill="#ddd810" cx="2.5" cy="3" r="2"/>
                                                                                <circle id="oval2" fill="#ddd810" cx="7.5" cy="2" r="2"/>
                                                                              </g>
                                                                            </g>
                                                                          </svg>
                                                                        </label>
<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change
1) id="checkbox-ins" to class="checkbox-ins"
2) In css styles change all #checkbox-ins to .checkbox-ins